# RenderPartial from master page failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages, renderpartial

I have a call to RenderPartial() from a master page that's returning empty on a remote server. Works fine on the local dev server. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have some kind of code smell in your partial class. It's been almost three months now. Did you find out what the problem was?